# clean form data only if creating model, not when updating

Tags: python, django

I am new in Django so this is very confusing.
I have this clean method to raise an error when the input data has the same year with existing data:

```
class FormSetting(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:    
        model = model
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean_date_year(self):
            clean_year = self.cleaned_data.get('effective_date')
            year = clean_year.strftime("%Y")
            check = model.objects.filter(effective_date__year=year).exists()
            if check:
                raise forms.ValidationError("The Year Input already here")
            return clean_year
```

But I also use the same page and the same form to make an update, how can I not clean it when I update it?

I am using date field so it was a date picker

```
            <fieldset>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <label >Effective Date</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                {{ form.effective_date.errors}}
                                {{ form.effective_date }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Please post your entire form's code.

Comment: i already tried and it work just fine, to fine that i cant even update my data anymore

Comment: So did you solve it? I don't get what you are trying to say.

Comment: no i didnt, the clean was worked. but if i cant update the data cause im using the same form. i have tried to hide the field but it still not working cause when form.save() it will try to clean the data and my updated data was not saved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should exclude the current instance from your queryset.

Try this:

```
class FormSetting(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:    
        model = model
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean_date_year(self):
            clean_year = self.cleaned_data.get('effective_date')
            year = clean_year.strftime("%Y")
            check = model.objects.filter(effective_date__year=year)
            if self.instance:
                check = check.exclude(id=self.instance.id)
            if check.exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError("The Year Input already here")
            return clean_year
```